# How to stop the Windows command line from outputting an empty line after each command?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm redirecting a batch file's output into a text file and don't want blank lines between each command. I realise I could post-process with a perl one-liner, but would rather not. Is there an option somewhere to suppress these unnecessary blank lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cmd` always outputs a new line *before* it prints its prompt. This means that something like

```
> echo foo
foo

> _
```

will always have that blank line since `echo` prints a line break automatically. However, something like

```
> set /p x=foo<nul
foo
> _
```

will not have the empty line in between since above is the the trick that allows printing stuff *without* a trailing line break. Still, the prompt appears at the beginning of the next line.

This is presumably done to have the prompt *always* at the start of the line, regardless how messed-up the last command's output was. On UNIX-likes it's common to find your prompt in the middle of the line since the last command didn't print a newline.

But there doesn't seem to be a way to prevent his behavior.

You can easily pipe whatever you're doing there through

```
findstr /r /v /c:"^$"
```

though.

Comment: On UNIX, you can put a control sequence in your prompt to 1) go to the start of the current line (CR, `"\015"`) , and 2) clear from cursor to end of line (ESC + [2K, `"\033[2K"`).

Comment: Did I miss something about Windows being UNIX now?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the commands you are running as they may be configured to do this after they are run - you would want to see if they have a non verbose option (However, I doubt this would help).

The other thing to try would be to put this at the beginning:

> @Echo off

Unfortunately though, I don't think you are going to have a lot of luck as I think all commands put a line break after they have finished (It is what returns/brings up the command prompt when finished.

Your best bet would be to use a post processing tool and simply remove the line breaks, but I do not know a good one to recommend.